# rowSums adding new column to dataframe but not adding the values

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, rowsum

I have a table that I'm trying to add multiple columns together in a new column. I've tried simple rowSums in different forms and it will create the new column but the values don't add.

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 25 | 15 | 25 |
| 99 | 42 | 20 | 35 |

I've tried

```
df$col5 <- rowSums(df[c("col1","col2","col3",col4")])
```

and

```
df <- df %>% mutate(col5 = rowSums(select(.,"col1","col2","col3",col4")
```

and

```
df <- df %>% mutate(col5 = sum(c_across(col1:col4)
```

But each time it returns

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 25 | 15 | 25 | *NA* |
| 99 | 42 | 20 | 35 | *NA* |

Comment: Try to add `na.rm = TRUE` into `rowSums()`

Comment: `rowSums(df, na.rm = TRUE)` works well for me.

Comment: Yeah, that was it, nulls were screwing up the calculation. Thanks!